# Apache2 weird redirection. (Default site overriding others)

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have just moved from Amazon EC2 to another VPS, running Ubuntu 12.04 on both of them. 
But now I get some very strange redirections.

No matter which domain name I access using http (port 80) I end up on the same domain. I have no redirections to this domain.

http://domain1.com works fine, but http://domain2.com redirects to http://domain1.com
Even if I just enter the IP-adress, I get domain1.com. It seems Apache2 can't resolve what name the request is coming from.

If I access over SSL at https://domain2.com, it loads just fine with no redirection.

I think I deleted the "default.conf" file in the "sites-enabled"-folder just after installing apache2. Can this have any influence?

Here is the `apache2ctl -S` output:

```
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:5
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.domain2.com
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com.conf:10)
         port 443 namevhost domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com.conf:10)
         port 443 namevhost domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2.com.conf:9)
                 alias www.domain2.com
         port 443 namevhost domain3.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain3.com.conf:2)
                 alias www.domain3.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

And this is my domain1.com.conf (completely similar to domain2.com.conf except for the domain names):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAdmin my@email.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerName domain1.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain1.com/domain1.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain1.com/domain1.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain1.com/sub.class1.server.ca.pem

    # Security settings for SSL
    SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 2):

The default.conf in /etc/apache/sites-available isn't special - but when it's listed as the first file in /etc/apache/sites-enabled (usually as 00-default.conf, so it is first in the list) then it will be the default. If that isn't there, then whatever else (like domain1.conf) is listed first is then the default site that will be shown if the URL isn't caught by any of the other vhosts listed in the other files.

Comment: It seems like the server doesn't know what domain name the request is coming from, and therefore just serves the default site.

Comment: I never resolved the issue, but reinstalled the server with Ubuntu 14.04LTS instead. This solved my problems...

Answer (score 0):

`https://my.ionos.com/settings-general`

check this option `Set Hosting as your homepage`

And then redirect to default site won't happen.